# Error loading Seaside 3.1 onto latest Pharo 3.0 image

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

The error I get is in the image below.  This is with a fresh, latest Pharo 3.0 image hosted at PharoCloud.
[image]

Edit: when I close out of the error and try to run the commands again, I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: You should be able to debug that error by either right clicking on the `Object <none>` entry or by using the triangle in the top right corner of the window (I don't remember). If you can get a debugger open, can you post the stack?

Comment: Do you also get this locally with a standard image (i.e. not a one-click download) ? I am unable to reproduce this.

Comment: It is with a standard image.  There is no sources file in the directory; it is the image only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the sources file fixed it.  Yay!